# Using t-test to compare multiple slopes?

Tags: linear-model, experiment-design, model-comparison

I work with an escape response. Basically, I want to find differences between animals that should run and animals that stay still when a stimulus is applied to them. I've been trying several approaches related to velocity and normalization (due to non-normal data) but lately I've been thinking there could be an easier way to analyse the data.

My crude data is position as a function of time. Here's a plot of 28 animals for a specific time lapse with linear regression for each case.

[image]

There's some animals that doesn't look nice adjusted to this lm but I think I can fix that by using total movement instead of position (if an animal is located at 3 and moves to 6 but then comes back I should have a total movement of 6 instead of zero).

Since this is only one trial of stimulation and I have several ones to do I was wondering if it is correct to use the individual absolut slopes as the "only" value for each trial for each animal. If it is, then one could use a simple t-test find differences.

Besides, I was trying to figure out a correct way to discard outliers (differentiate zero from noise and discard "big runners"). I think this approach might help but I don't know if it is correct. Here's the table with slopes, just in case. Maybe the linear model is not the best one and I should come back to nl-regressions and fighting with initial values.

```
variable slope value
UT1      -0.14
UT2      -25.59
UT3      8.36
UT4      62.73
UT5      -2.68
UT6       5.18
UT7      2.23
UT8     -18.41
UT9      10.91
UT10    -22.55
UT11     -5.73
UT12     -10.91
UT13       3.45
UT14      8.82
TR1       17.86
TR2      42.23
TR3      -2.00
TR4       6.55
TR5       1.36
TR6      4.82
TR7     -1.00
TR8      0.00
TR9      -58.00
TR10       5.77
TR11       0.00
TR12    -1.18
TR13    24.09
TR14    -0.55
```

Thank you very much

Comment: The slope is a reasonable point of departure for this study but I believe there may be better measures of "run a lot." The slope approximately measures the average speed *in the direction determined by the net motion during the entire period.* When an animal runs out and runs back, the slope will be grossly biased low. Also, it does not seem that direction matters: you are interested in *speed* rather than *velocity.* Thus, you actually have much more and better information than is captured in any slope: you have the ten distances between each successive pair of observations. Why not use them?

Comment: What do you mean with "you have the ten distances between each successive pair of observations. Why not use them?" Do you mean using the difference between every two points like an instant speed? I've tried that already, the plots look very nice but the analysis is far more complicated

Comment: You can make the analysis as simple or complicated as you wish. The first thing is to explore the distributions of those speeds. Then, if you like, use an average, such as their mean, median, or Winsorized mean, as a proxy for each set of speeds. That is likely to be more meaningful than the slopes--and is simpler to compute and interpret. But also of interest would be some measure of dispersion, because that could differentiate animals that constantly moved from those that ran back and forth or those that sat and suddenly jumped away.

Comment: @whuber I've tried mean but since the distribution of the speeds its not normal and the dispersion is huge (sometimes 3 times the mean) I jumped to median. It didn't help much. I've tried some normalizations that work for some cases ("work" means correlates with 20 years of published data). And finally I tried some fitting analysis (you can see one example here http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92748/multi-peak-gaussian-fit-in-r/93032#93032 ) But I would really want to find a unique way to analyse all the experiments. Keep in mind that this is only ONE TRIAL of forty per experiment

Comment: It is not evident what you mean by "didn't help much," so I have no suggestions to make in that regard. If "running a lot" is what you're interested in, then it behooves you to analyze a reasonable measure of running, even if it should lead to technical difficulties in the analysis. If you instead elect to alter your variable in order to make the analysis more tractable, you will get results that (at best) only indirectly relate to what you are really interested in. You have a rich dataset, so you should be optimistic concerning what you can learn from it.

Comment: Why don't you just use variance of the position?

Comment: @Bill I don't know if I understand what you mean. Why use a variance analysis when I know variance is huge and not reproducible from one experiment to another?

Comment: You say your goal is: "I want to find differences between animals that run a lot and animals that stay still."  An animal which stays still has a 0 variance in its position.  An animal which runs a lot has a large variance in its position, unless it is running in tiny circles.  Is running in tiny circles a common behavior?  UT1, for example, has a significant variance although a nearly zero slope.  TR11's variance isn't huge.  It stays still and has a zero variance.

Comment: @Bill I understood what you ment. I was talking of UT's and TR's variance as a group. It is true that UT1 has some variance but it is also true that what you see as movement there is the minimum movement I can measure (my 1 in arbitrary units) It's just like a leg strech...One of my problems is that I can't differenciate a genuine response from this noise. My guess BOTH UT1 and TR11 should be outliers because I can't tell the difference if they actively stayed still or ramdomly moved just 1 in the two stimulation seconds. That's why I want to condense all stimulation period in one number.