# Sum of two gaussian curves

Tags: r, nls

I have a set of raw chromatographic data (x,y) where I'm trying to evaluate the area of two unresolved peaks separately using gaussian approximations in R. I found this answer from a few years ago (the second answer with 3 upvotes)

[Multi-peak Gaussian fit in R](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/92748/multi-peak-gaussian-fit-in-r)

This seems like it's the perfect solution for what I'm trying to do, but when I get to the final step of running the nls ("fit1") I'm getting a "singular gradient" error.

The unresolved peak data looks like this:

```
data<-structure(list(RT = c(0.996866666666667, 1.00353333333334, 1.0102, 
1.01686666666667, 1.02353333333334, 1.0302, 1.03686666666667, 
1.04353333333334, 1.0502, 1.05686666666667, 1.06353333333334, 
1.0702, 1.07686666666667, 1.08353333333334, 1.0902, 1.09686666666667, 
1.10353333333334, 1.1102, 1.11686666666667, 1.12353333333334, 
1.1302, 1.13686666666667, 1.14353333333334, 1.1502, 1.15686666666667, 
1.16353333333334, 1.1702, 1.17686666666667, 1.18353333333334, 
1.1902, 1.19686666666667, 1.20353333333334, 1.2102, 1.21686666666667, 
1.22353333333334, 1.2302, 1.23686666666667, 1.24353333333334, 
1.2502, 1.25686666666667, 1.26353333333334, 1.2702, 1.27686666666667, 
1.28353333333334, 1.2902, 1.29686666666667), mAU = c(0, 0.010013580322266, 
0.090122222900391, 0.185489654541016, 0.28371810913086, 0.370025634765625, 
0.43630599975586, 0.480175018310547, 0.504493713378907, 0.515460968017578, 
0.519752502441407, 0.521659851074219, 0.524520874023438, 0.535011291503907, 
0.576019287109375, 0.673770904541016, 0.83303451538086, 1.04045867919922, 
1.27553939819336, 1.52683258056641, 1.77049636840821, 1.98650360107422, 
2.17294692993164, 2.34794616699219, 2.5320053100586, 2.7303695678711, 
2.94160842895508, 3.15999984741211, 3.38077545166016, 3.60202789306641, 
3.82232666015625, 4.03738021850586, 4.19473648071289, 4.15945053100586, 
3.84902954101563, 3.29732894897461, 2.62928009033203, 1.9221305847168, 
1.23453140258789, 0.695228576660157, 0.378131866455078, 0.244617462158203, 
0.174522399902344, 0.106334686279297, 0.038623809814453, 0)), row.names = 150:195, class = "data.frame")
plot(data)
```

[image: plot of data]

I think part of the issue is that there's not a defined valley between the two peaks. Ideally I'd be able to do this with any general dataset without having any previous knowledge about where peaks are (means and stdevs). Any alternative solutions would also be appreciated.

Comment: What is it you want, exactly? The area under the curve? The distance between the peaks?

Comment: I need the area under both edit:peaks, the one at ~1.06min and the one at ~1.21min.

Comment: Do you mean the area under both peaks? And do you need them separately? Or is one number sufficient?

Comment: Yep, both peaks, sorry. I need them separately, I can find the area under the curve as a whole no problem, I just don't have a good way to evaluate each peak separately.

Comment: Well, I think you need to find the peaks first with a peak detector. If you have a valley (the curve has a negative slope in-between the peaks somewhere), that should be fairly straight-forward with a standard peak detection algorithm. If you don't have a valley, like in this dataset, you'll have to get more creative. The inflection points might help out, here; you could partition the dataset into regions based on intervals between inflection points. In this dataset, I see these inflection points: $[1.025, 1.07, 1.15, 1.24].$ That might be a start...

Comment: Here's the downer with finding inflection points: you have to differentiate the signal, which can GREATLY increase the influence of noise. Integration smoothes, differentiation makes signals more angular. One way you could mitigate that is to fit a $6$th degree polynomial to your curve, and find the inflection points of that. Why $6?$ Because you need to find $4$ inflection points, which means $4$ roots of the second derivative. Integrate twice to get a $6$th degree poly. Curve fitting is a kind of integration, so that can mitigate noise.

Comment: That was my thought as well, though I'm pretty sure that's what the script I linked does. My other thought was if I could approximate the obvious peak (~1.21min) first, then subtract out the datapoints used for that approximation and find the maximum of what's left, that should more or less be the peak max of the smaller peak.

Comment: That's a good idea, too: find one peak. Fit a Gaussian to that peak and find its area. Subtract out that Gaussian from your data. Find the other peak (should be MUCH easier to find after subtracting out the bigger Gaussian). Get the area under that peak. When you fit the data to your first Gaussian, you're going to want to "window" it: only use, say, 5-10 data points on either side of the peak. That way, the other peak doesn't influence your fit.

Comment: any good methods for doing that? i found the maximum, used that as my "mean" value and used peak width at 1/2 peak height = 2.534*sigma to find the stdev and tried to use dnorm to fit to the curve but it did not work at all. Also i'm not sure how I would evaluate peak width at 1/2 peak height for the smaller peak since half of it is missing, i'd have to fill in the datapoints assuming they're symmetrical to what can be seen

Comment: Afraid I'm not an R guy at all, so I don't know what's available. In `scipy` there are generalized algorithms for fitting whatever curves you want. You can specify the form of the function to fit, and `scipy` does the rest. I would be shocked if R didn't have the equivalent.

Comment: I don't think your $2.534\sigma$ is correct for half peak height. I get $\pm\sqrt{2\ln(2)}\,\sigma\approx\pm 1.17741\sigma.$

Comment: The basic problem is that the large peak is so far from Gaussian that trying to a fit a Gaussian to it will incur an error of the same magnitude as the smaller peak, so all bets are off.  I would look for a scientific or engineering explanation for the linear increase in response with retention time between 1.10 and 1.22 and go on from there.

Comment: oh yep you're right, i left in a factor of 2 by accident (also a typo, meant 2.355). that could explain the bad fit.

honestly I think the deviation from gaussian is ok as long as the approximation is consistent across multiple runs. I think this is how some of Agilent's integrators approximate peak area in their deconvolution algorithms (but with the aid of MS data, which I don't have here). I can evaluate area at 1/2 peak height, I just want a secondary approximation that confirms my data and shows my assumptions are valid. I suppose a triangle approximation could work as well

Comment: did some more reading, just realized what i'm looking for is not a density function but an Exponentially Modified Gaussian Distribution (EMG). Found some more R packages that deal with these but none seem to be super helpful

Comment: Whether or not you perceive the deviation from Guassian as "ok," I suspect that might be the original cause of the "singular gradient" error you report.  Thus, if you would like to overcome this problem, one approach that is likely to be effective would be to relax this Gaussian requirement for the peak shapes.